# Pasar variable entre Forms

Tags: c#

Quiero pasar una variable de un formulario a otro. Es un formulario del estilo de una factura en el que del form1 (producto principal) voy a otro form2 (producto secundario), pero en el form2 hago cálculos que necesito pasar al form1 para totalizar el precio (es como una factura). Sé que es muy general, pero esa es la idea: pasar variables, valores o datos de un form a otro.

Comment: ¿Usas alguna base de datos? ¿Puedes poner algo de lo que hayas hecho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de indicar que formulario llevara el parámetro por ejemplo

```
public class Formulario1(){
   int precio = 200;
   Formulario2.Show(precio);
}
```

En el otro formulario debes de indicar que parametro va a recibir

```
 public class Formulario2(int precio){
    int total = precio;
  }
```

Comment: Gracias hermanos... Me ayudaron mucho... Les agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Crea una clase estática para intercambiar información entre tus formularios.

```
public static class InformationExchange
{
    public static int Value1ToExchange { get; set; }
}
```

Podrás llamar a esta clase desde ambos formularios y acceder a sus propiedades y modificarlas simplemente con:

```
InformationExchange.Value1ToExchange
```